# Detect click on JTable: sometimes not recognized

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I've this code to detect click on JTable

```
table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e)
    {

        int row= table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int col= table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

        if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
        {

            System.out.println ("Doppio Click");

        }

    }

});
```

This code work great the problem is that if I click on a row and before mouse button up I move mouse up the click is not detected but the row is selected in my JTable. Can anyone know how to fix that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Use mouseDown to store the row/col (I'd personally put it in a Point Object, as it easier to detect for nulls, but that's just me) then act on in the release or clicked method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MouseListener.mouseReleased` or `MouseListener.mousePressed` events instead (to detect double clicking that way is tricker but could be done).

Comment: Yes, that' s is the solution. I' ve tried it before your answer and It works great. The problem is for the double click now!